# How to plot an unstructured numpy array with a legend?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, legend, ode

#### Is it possible, when plotting an n-dimensional unstructured array with `matplotlib`, to produce a legend label for each dimension?

- The solution of a system of ODEs, when using [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), is returned as an array of shape (100, 5) for 5 variables.
- I want to plot the solution from one system as lines, so `plt.plot(sol, '-')`, reset the color cycle, then plot the same 5 again calculated using another ODE system, using `plt.plot(sol_estimate, '--')`.
- This way, I have the 5 variables in one plot, the exact, as lines, and the approximate, as dashes.
- I can try to play with the opacity later in case the solutions are hard to differentiate
- The primary objective is to get the legend for the 10 lines in an easy way.
- Best would be some loop since we can call them u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u1_e, u2_e, u3_e, u4_e, u5_e.
- Is this possible in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This example only uses a second order ODE, but should get the idea across for how to add a legend.

  - Using the example from [scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)
- Convert the unstructured array into a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), by adding `dtype` to the `sol` array.

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# ode system
def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

b = np.arange(0.50, 0, -0.25)
c = 5.0
y0 = [np.pi - 0.1, 0.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

ls = ['-', '--']  # list of linestyles
count = 0  # used to index the current linestyle
for i in b:
    
    sol = odeint(pend, y0, t, args=(i, c))

    type_to_set = 'float64'  # specify the type you need (e.g. 'float64')
    dtype = np.dtype([(f'{x}_ode:{i}', type_to_set) for x in range(sol.shape[1])])  # create names and dtypes list
    sol_updated = sol.astype(type_to_set).view(dtype)  # add names and dtypes to sol
    
    # plot
    # plt.figure()  # if you want separate plots for each group uncomment this line & put plt.legend in 4 spaces, so it's just after the plotting loop
    for name in sol_updated.dtype.names:
        plt.plot(t, sol_updated[name], linestyle=ls[count], label=name)

    count += 1  # add 1 to the markers indexer
    plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

- This is 2 sets of (101, 2) arrays on the same plot with unique line styles for each `ode` solution group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had to add a `plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)` at the end of the outer for loop and it met all my criteria since I wanted to have the estimates and originals in the same color, just one as solid line and one as dashed.